# iOS 9.3 simulator in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10

I need to test my app on iPhone 4S.
In Xcode 10, I've went to Xcode > Preferences > Components > Simulators
and I've downloaded "iOS 9.3 Simulator"
[image]

But I don't see it on the simulator list next to the Run button.
[image]

Any idea, how to run this iOS 9.3 simulator in Xcode 10?

Comment: Is your app's Deployment Target set to 9.3?

Comment: @DonMag Deployment Target is set to 9.0

Comment: 9.0 for both the **Project** and the **Target** settings?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, both.

Comment: Hmmm... if you select "Add Additional Simulators..." does it give you the option to add an iPhone 4s (or other model) Simulator with iOS 9.3?

Comment: No, only the iOS 11 and iOS 10 simulators.

Comment: Odd... I assume you've quit / restarted Xcode? Maybe try adding 8.2 and see if it shows up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a simulator using the simulator os version. You have only downloaded the iOS version software.

To add a device follow: Window > Devices & Simulators. (or cmd + shift + 2)

Then at the bottom of the list press the + icon. This should allow you to add a device running the selected iOS version.

Comment: It's correct, but you didn't have to minus my question.

Comment: It wasn't me who minused (is that even a word?) your question. ‍♂️ I just upvoted it for you.

Comment: Ok, so sorry for suspecting you.

Answer (score 6):

> iOS 9.3 (9.3 - 13E233) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3
>   (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts
>   after macOS 10.14.99.) (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is
>   not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the Deployment Targets at 9.x, then navigate to:

Xcode > Preferences > Components

There you will see a list of additional simulators to install. These can sometimes take an really long time to download, and I've found [this](https://hackernoon.com/manually-install-ios-simulators-in-xcode-f7e4bbe50753) article to be very helpful in speeding up the process.

Comment: I was like why the heck is the simulator dropdown not showing any devices, now I changed the app Deployment Target to 9.x and viola, dropdown started showing devices! Thank you!